# Filter documents that have id in another collection in MongoDB with aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have two collection. collectionA and collectionB
collection A has following documents

```
db={
  "collectiona": [
    {
      "_id": "6173ddf33ed09368a094e68a",
      "title": "a"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61wefdf33ed09368a094e6dc",
      "title": "b"
    }, 
    
    {
      "_id": "61wefdfewf09368a094ezzz",
      "title": "c"
    }, 
    
    
  ],
  "collectionb": [
    {
      "_id": "6173ddf33ed0wef368a094zq",
      "collectionaID": "6173ddf33ed09368a094e68a",
      "data": [
        {
          "userID": "123",
          "visibility": false,
          "response": false
        },
        {
          "userID": "2345",
          "visibility": true,
          "response": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "6173ddf33ed09368awef4e68g",
      "collectionaID": "61wefdf33ed09368a094e6dc",
      "data": [
        {
          "userID": "5678",
          "visibility": false,
          "response": false
        },
        {
          "userID": "674",
          "visibility": true,
          "response": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

}

So What I need is documents from collection A which  has response false  in collection B
and document should be sorted by first the ones that have visibility false and then the ones that have visibility true

for eg. userID : 123 should get 3 documents

```
 {
      "_id": "6173ddf33ed09368a094e68a",
      "title": "a"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61wefdf33ed09368a094e6dc",
      "title": "b"
    }, 
    
    {
      "_id": "61wefdfewf09368a094ezzz",
      "title": "c"
    },
```

whereas userID 2345 should get two

```
 {
      "_id": "61wefdf33ed09368a094e6dc",
      "title": "b"
    }, 

    {
      "_id": "61wefdfewf09368a094ezzz",
      "title": "c"
    },
```

User 674 will receive 3 objects from collection A but second would be in the last as it has visibility true for that document

```
{
          "_id": "6173ddf33ed09368a094e68a",
          "title": "a"
        },
        
        {
          "_id": "61wefdfewf09368a094ezzz",
          "title": "c"
        },
     {
          "_id": "61wefdf33ed09368a094e6dc",
          "title": "b"
        },
```

MongoDB Playground link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/3rLry0FPlw-
Really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: How user `123` with collectionID `6173ddf33ed09368a094e68a` has relation with titles `b` and `c`?

Comment: Hi, The documents that are not present in collection B will always come for all user. Let me know if that helps your query

Answer (score 0):

You can start from collectionA:

1. `$lookup` the collectionB for the record related to the user specified
2. filter out collectionB documents according to `response`
3. assign a helper `sortrank` field based on the `visibility` and whether `collectionaID` is a match
4. `$sort` according to `sortrank`
5. wrangle back to the raw collection A

```
db.collectiona.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collectionb",
      let: {
        aid: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $unwind: "$data"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$data.userID",
                    "2345"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$collectionaID",
                    "$$aid"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "collB"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "collB.data.response": {
        $ne: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$collB",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sortrank": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$collB.data.visibility",
              false
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$collB.collectionaID",
                  "$_id"
                ]
              },
              "then": 3,
              "else": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortrank: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      collB: false,
      sortrank: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZWSq8x6gqp) for your reference.

Comment: Hi @ray thanks for answering. But this does not work as an answer. 

https://mongoplayground.net/p/uQIIXUW2env 
I added one more document in collection B but the answer is not expected since after adding that document. User 2 should get only two documents from collection A 

Let me know If I can help you solve this query in any way. Thanks for trying

Comment: Your logic is rather complicated and quite hard to construct query based on your schema. Can you clarify: 1. User 2 means userID: "123" ? 2. Which 2 documents should be expected and why? [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZWSq8x6gqp) is another trial that I guess the behaviour, see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay in order to clear my problem. I will write a good situation here. 
Suppose collection a is called articles and collection b is userTakenArticles 
User taken articles store the details about what user has seen a particular article and have they responded to that article so that's why you see two flags visibility and response.

Comment: Now what we want is only those articles from collection A which hasn't been responded by users. first sorted by those articles which haven't been visible to user and then the ones already visible to user. Hope that makes sense. If you think a better schema for this problem let me know.

Comment: Would be great if you can confirm again the updated solution in playground([Copied here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZWSq8x6gqp)) is what you are looking for. You clarification helps a lot :) It is just when we come to schema design, the context required usually are far more than a common SO question can holds. If you need help on the schema, I would suggest you ask a separate question and keep this question more focused on the current query problem.